# how to disable end user upload file via chatter?

Tags: chatter

I want to disable some special user upload file via chatter. But, when i remove following permission from profile, the end user still can upload. i was try clear cache and re-login again. So, is there some other setting for this?

In Profile:

Remove: Create and Own New Chatter Groups

Remove: Invite Customers To Chatter

Remove: Create and Share Links to Chatter Files

Remove: Insert System Field Values for Chatter Feeds

Comment: There is another approach if its feasible for redesign...Instead of using repository ( via chatter upload ) Library's can be used for repository ( upload ) and for other users "Content" tab can be exposed which doesn't allow upload..This approach can be used if its not mandatory that users should use chatter.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can do that. But maybe try to turn off CRUD permission for the "FILES" object on your profile and disable the tab too.

Comment: There is no files object.

Comment: Yeah you're right, my bad. Actually I don't think we can restrict user from uploading files in Chatter. Don't hesitate to vote for this idea on [IdeaExchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KP6b)